# Windows Service Stop working suddenly and work fine after server restart

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have few service developed in .net. they are working fine but some time suddenly stop working and dont run even i restart them. the only solution is to restart the server. Once server restart everything work fine as previous

Comment: This is an extremely vague question, you will have to provide more information.

Comment: It could be your code, it could be something environmental, its extremely hard to tell, id first look at your event log

Answer (score 1):

I would check Windows Event Viewer for a start to maybe get the error being thrown by .NET Framework when the service stops working.  If a server restart is required to get it to run again, it probably is something environmental caused by your service.

With the details provided in your question, that's the best I can advise.